# Why "InvalidRequest" on 2nd hit of page 2 of pagination?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I do pagination and a link that works to page 2 looks like this

`/q?query=regionID%3D4700188&cursor=False:CqoECuYBCtgB_wDAQM8HgAD_AP8A_wD__wDAQCQA_wD_AP8A_wD_AP__AMBAHAD_AP8A_wD_AP8A___-9wllzNf_Z_-_jIGSkJGLnpCPjZCVmpyL_wB0baCgmYuMoKD_AF2ej4-akZiWkZr_AHN0bZaRm5qH_wBdnpuM_wBzdG2bkJyglpv_AF2emMaFmZLOiZ2RrZedzL2Gnc2Pk6bMrYa8iIysvpS5lLi0nsrOiLKy_wBzf56YxoWZks6JnZGtl53MvYadzY-TpsythryIjKy-lLmUuLSeys6IsrL_AP_-EDIh4o_3av1KJSkSDURvY3VtZW50SW5kZXganwEoQU5EIChJUyAiY3VzdG9tZXJfbmFtZSIgImFwcGVuZ2luZSIpIChJUyAiZ3JvdXBfbmFtZSIgInN-bW9udGFvcHJvamVjdCIpIChJUyAibmFtZXNwYWNlIiAiIikgKElTICJpbmRleF9uYW1lIiAiYWRzIikgKEVRIDQ3MDAxODguMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAgInNuYnJfcmVnaW9uSUQiKSk6GwoOKE4gc2RhdGVfZGF0ZSkQARkAAABzFPtzQjoaCg0oTiBzbmJyX2hvdXIpEAEZAAAAAAAAEEA6HAoPKE4gc25icl9taW51dGUpEAEZAAAAAAAAMkBKHAgBOhVzdDpidGlfZ2VuZXJpY19zY29yZXJAkE5SGQoMKE4gb3JkZXJfaWQpEAEZAAAAAAAA8P8`

But every now and then, seemingly random, I get error message that doesn't seem to be a timeout but an error with the query. When I hit reload I got this error, is it a timeout error?

```
 "GET /q?query=regionID%3D4700188&cursor=False:CqoECuYBCtgB_wDAQM8HgAD_AP8A_wD__wDAQCQA_wD_AP8A_wD_AP__AMBAHAD_AP8A_wD_AP8A___-9wllzNf_Z_-_jIGSkJGLnpCPjZCVmpyL_wB0baCgmYuMoKD_AF2ej4-akZiWkZr_AHN0bZaRm5qH_wBdnpuM_wBzdG2bkJyglpv_AF2emMaFmZLOiZ2RrZedzL2Gnc2Pk6bMrYa8iIysvpS5lLi0nsrOiLKy_wBzf56YxoWZks6JnZGtl53MvYadzY-TpsythryIjKy-lLmUuLSeys6IsrL_AP_-EDIh4o_3av1KJSkSDURvY3VtZW50SW5kZXganwEoQU5EIChJUyAiY3VzdG9tZXJfbmFtZSIgImFwcGVuZ2luZSIpIChJUyAiZ3JvdXBfbmFtZSIgInN-bW9udGFvcHJvamVjdCIpIChJUyAibmFtZXNwYWNlIiAiIikgKElTICJpbmRleF9uYW1lIiAiYWRzIikgKEVRIDQ3MDAxODguMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAgInNuYnJfcmVnaW9uSUQiKSk6GwoOKE4gc2RhdGVfZGF0ZSkQARkAAABzFPtzQjoaCg0oTiBzbmJyX2hvdXIpEAEZAAAAAAAAEEA6HAoPKE4gc25icl9taW51dGUpEAEZAAAAAAAAMkBKHAgBOhVzdDpidGlfZ2VuZXJpY19zY29yZXJAkE5SGQoMKE4gb3JkZXJfaWQpEAEZAAAAAAAA8P8 HTTP/1.1" 200 8611 "http://www.koolbusiness.com/q?query=regionID%3D4700188" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36" "www.koolbusiness.com" ms=133 cpu_ms=42 cpm_usd=0.060962 app_engine_release=1.8.1 instance=00c61b117cd1983617eb4b0968a84b71874563
D 2013-07-06 06:20:37.095
query regionID=4700188
E 2013-07-06 06:20:37.120
Search failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2013e.368581150756737282/search_demo.py", line 87, in find_documents
    return index.search(query)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 2732, in search
    _CheckStatus(response.status())
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 413, in _CheckStatus
    raise _ERROR_MAP[status.code()](status.error_detail())
InvalidRequest: Failed to execute search request "regionID=4700188"
```

Code

```
def find_documents(query_string, limit, cursor):
    try:
        date_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='date',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime.now().date())

        hr_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='hour',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime.now().hour)

        min_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='minute',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime.now().minute)

        # Sort up to 5000 matching results by subject in descending order

        sort = search.SortOptions(expressions=[date_desc, hr_desc,
                                  min_desc], limit=10000)

        # Set query options

        options = search.QueryOptions(limit=limit, cursor=cursor,
                sort_options=sort, number_found_accuracy=10000)  # the number of results to return

            # returned_fields=['author', 'subject', 'summary'],
            # snippeted_fields=['content']

        query = search.Query(query_string=query_string, options=options)
        index = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME)

        # Execute the query

        return index.search(query)
    except search.Error:
        logging.exception('Search failed')
    return None




regions_in = [
        ('3', u'Entire India'),
    ('4703187', u'Andaman & Nicobar Islands'),
    ('4694186', u'Andhra Pradesh'),
    ('4699188', u'Arunachal Pradesh'),
    ('4692186', u'Assam'),
    ('4702186', u'Bihar'),
    ('4698185', u'Chandigarh'),
    ('4676188', u'Chhattisgarh'),
    ('4691190', u'Dadra & Nagar Haveli'),
    ('4704183', u'Daman & Diu'),
    ('4699183', u'Delhi'),
    ('4702187', u'Goa'),
    ('4691189', u'Gujarat'),
    ('4700186', u'Haryana'),
    ('4703185', u'Himachal Pradesh'),
    ('4694187', u'Jammu & Kashmir'),
    ('4699189', u'Jharkhand'),
    ('4701185', u'Karnataka'),
    ('4695189', u'Kerala'),
    ('4700189', u'Lakshadweep'),
    ('4697186', u'Madhya Pradesh'),
    ('4694184', u'Maharashtra'),
    ('4700187', u'Manipur'),
    ('4703186', u'Meghalaya'),
    ('4698184', u'Mizoram'),
    ('4692187', u'Nagaland'),
    ('4696185', u'Orissa'),
    ('4676189', u'Pondicherry'),
    ('4693185', u'Punjab'),
    ('4701186', u'Rajasthan'),
    ('4701187', u'Sikkim'),
    ('4701188', u'Tamil Nadu'),
    ('4697187', u'Tripura'),
    ('4699190', u'Uttaranchal'),
    ('4692188', u'Uttar Pradesh'),
    ('4700188', u'West Bengal'),
    ]

class RegionSearch(SearchBaseHandler):

    """Handles regional search requests."""

    def get(self):
        """Handles a get request with a query."""

        category = None
        cityentity = None
        next_cursor = None
        country = ''
        if self.request.host.find('hipheap') > -1: country = 'USA'
        elif self.request.host.find('koolbusiness') > -1: country = 'India'
        elif self.request.host.find('montao') > -1: country = 'Brasil'
        number_returned = 0
        regionname = None
        cityname = None
        regionentity = None
        region = None
        cursor = self.request.get('cursor')
        uri = urlparse(self.request.uri)
        query = ''
        regionID = regionid = self.request.get('regionid', 0)
        cityID = cityid = self.request.get('cityid', 0)
        categoryID = categoryid = self.request.get('category', 0)
        if uri.query:
            query = parse_qs(uri.query)
            try:
                query = query['query'][0]
            except KeyError, err:
                query = ''
                # logging.info('KeyError')

        # Try find region ID and/or cityID and categoryID a.s.a.p.

        if regionid or query.find('regionID') > -1:
            regionID = re.sub("^regionID=(\d+).*", r'\1', query)
            region = Region.get_by_id(long(regionID))
            regionname = region.name

        if regionid:
            regionID = regionid
            region = Region.get_by_id(long(regionID))
            regionname = region.name

        if cityid or query.find('cityID') > -1:
            cityID = re.sub("^.*cityID=(\d+).*", r'\1', query)
            if cityid: cityID = cityid
            city = montaomodel.City.get_by_id(long(cityID))
            cityID = city.key().id()
            cityentity = city
            cityname = city.name
            region = Region.get_by_id(long(city.region.key().id()))
            regionID = region.key().id()

        if categoryid or query.find('category') > -1:
            categoryID = re.sub("^.*category=(\d+).*", r'\1', query)
            if categoryid: categoryID = categoryid

        logging.debug('query %s', query)

        if cursor: results = find_documents(query, 50, search.Cursor(cursor))
        else: results = find_documents(query, 50, search.Cursor())

        if results and results.cursor: next_cursor = results.cursor.web_safe_string
        namedquery = query
        query = query.replace(' and company_ad=0', ''
                              ).replace(' and company_ad=1', ''
                ).replace(' and category:(6010 OR 6020 OR 6030 OR 6040 OR 6090)'
                          , ''
                          ).replace(' and category:(6010 OR 6020 OR 6030 OR 6040 OR 6090)'
                                    , ''
                                    ).replace(' and category:(1020 OR 1010 OR 1030 OR 1050 OR 1080 OR 1100 OR 1090)'
                , ''
                ).replace(' and category:(2010 OR 2030 OR 2040 OR 2080 OR 2070)'
                          , ''
                          ).replace(' and category:(3040 OR 3050 OR 3030 OR 3060)'
                                    , ''
                                    ).replace(' and category:(4010 OR 4020 OR 4040 OR 4030 OR 4090 OR 4060 OR 4070)'
                , '')

        query = re.sub("regionID=\d+", '', query)
        query = query.replace('category and', '')
        query = query.replace('type=s', '')
        query = query.replace('type=w', '')
        query = query.replace('type=r', '')
        query = query.replace('type=b', '')
        query = query.replace('cityID and', '')
        query = query.replace('and ', '')
        query = query.replace(' and', '')
        query = query.replace('regionID', '')
        query = query.replace('=', '%3D')

        namedquery = namedquery.replace('=', '%3D')

        query = re.sub("cityID%3D\d+", '', query)
        query = re.sub("category%3D\d+", '', query)
        query = query.replace('  ', ' ')

        # to do: make into a dictionary for O(1) access


        if int(regionid) > 0: regionname = region_id_to_name[regionid]

        #if regionID and query.find('cityID') < 1:
        #    region = Region.get_by_id(long(regionID))

        form = SearchForm()

        form.w.choices = [
            ('4703187', u'Andaman & Nicobar Islands'),
            ('4694186', u'Andhra Pradesh'),
            ('4699188', u'Arunachal Pradesh'),
            ('4692186', u'Assam'),
            ('4702186', u'Bihar'),
            ('4698185', u'Chandigarh'),
            ('4676188', u'Chhattisgarh'),
            ('4691190', u'Dadra & Nagar Haveli'),
            ('4704183', u'Daman & Diu'),
            ('4699183', u'Delhi'),
            ('4702187', u'Goa'),
            ('4691189', u'Gujarat'),
            ('4700186', u'Haryana'),
            ('4703185', u'Himachal Pradesh'),
            ('4694187', u'Jammu & Kashmir'),
            ('4699189', u'Jharkhand'),
            ('4701185', u'Karnataka'),
            ('4695189', u'Kerala'),
            ('4700189', u'Lakshadweep'),
            ('4697186', u'Madhya Pradesh'),
            ('4694184', u'Maharashtra'),
            ('4700187', u'Manipur'),
            ('4703186', u'Meghalaya'),
            ('4698184', u'Mizoram'),
            ('4692187', u'Nagaland'),
            ('4696185', u'Orissa'),
            ('4676189', u'Pondicherry'),
            ('4693185', u'Punjab'),
            ('4701186', u'Rajasthan'),
            ('4701187', u'Sikkim'),
            ('4701188', u'Tamil Nadu'),
            ('4697187', u'Tripura'),
            ('4699190', u'Uttaranchal'),
            ('4692188', u'Uttar Pradesh'),
            ('4700188', u'West Bengal'),
            ]

        if region or cityentity:

            # to do:use memcache

            form.area.choices = []  # to do: use memcache for the list
            for cityitem in City.all().filter('region =',
                    region.key()).order('-vieworder').order('name'
                    ).fetch(99999):
                form.area.choices.append([str(cityitem.key().id()),
                        cityitem.name])
            if cityentity:
                form.area.data = str(cityentity.key().id())

            if self.request.host.find('hipheap') > -1:
                if region and (str(region.key().id()), region.name) \
                    in form.w_us.choices:
                    form.w_us.choices.remove((str(region.key().id()),
                            region.name))
            else:
                if region and (str(region.key().id()), region.name) \
                    in form.w.choices:
                    form.w.choices.remove((str(region.key().id()),
                            region.name))
        if region: regionname = region.name
        if results: number_returned = len(results.results)
        template_values = {
            'results': results,'regionname':regionname,
            'cursor': next_cursor,
            'country': country,
            'user': self.current_user,
            'number_returned': number_returned,
            'loggedin': self.logged_in,
            'VERSION': VERSION,
            'region': region,
            'regionname': regionname,
            'jobs_count': get_jobs_count(self, regionID, cityID),
            'estate_count': get_estate_count(self, regionID, cityID),
            'electronics_count': get_electronics_count(self, regionID,
                    cityID),
            'home_count': get_home_count(self, regionID, cityID),
            'leisure_count': get_leisure_count(self, regionID, cityID),
            'vehicles_count': get_vehicles_count(self, regionID,
                    cityID),
            'cityentity': cityentity,
            'request': self.request,
            'categoryID': categoryID,
            'form': form,
            'query': query,
            'namedquery': namedquery,
            'cityname': cityname,
            'category': category,
            }
        self.render_template('q.htm', template_values)


class India(SearchBaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        """Handles a get request with a query."""
        regionname = None
        country = 'India'
        cursor = self.request.get('cursor')
        region = None
        if self.request.host.find('hipheap') > -1: country = 'USA'
        elif self.request.host.find('koolbusiness') > -1: country = 'India'
        elif self.request.host.find('montao') > -1: country = 'Brasil'
        uri = urlparse(self.request.uri)
        query = ''
        if uri.query:
            query = parse_qs(uri.query)
            try:
                query = query['query'][0]
            except KeyError, err:
                query = ''
                # logging.info('KeyError')
        if cursor:
            results = find_documents(query, 50, search.Cursor(cursor))
        else:
            results = find_documents(query, 50, search.Cursor())
        next_cursor = None
        if results and results.cursor: next_cursor = results.cursor.web_safe_string
        query = query.replace(' and company_ad=0', ''
                              ).replace(' and company_ad=1', '')
        regionname = 'Entire India'
        regionID = 0
        cityID = 0
        form = SearchForm()
        form.w.choices = region_id_to_name
        template_values = {
            'regions':region_id_to_name,
            'form': form,
            'results': results,
            'cursor': next_cursor,
            'region': region,
            'country': country,
            'number_returned': len(results.results),
            'jobs_count': get_jobs_count_india(self, regionID, cityID),
            'estate_count': get_estate_count_india(self, regionID,
                    cityID),
            'electronics_count': get_electronics_count_india(self,
                    regionID, cityID),
            'home_count': get_home_count_india(self, regionID, cityID),
            'leisure_count': get_leisure_count_india(self, regionID,
                    cityID),
            'vehicles_count': get_vehicles_count_india(self, regionID,
                    cityID),
            'user': users.get_current_user(),
            'loggedin': self.logged_in,
            'region': region,
            'regionname': regionname,
            'city': '',
            'cityentity': None,
            'request': self.request,
            'form': SearchForm(),
            'query': query,
            }
        self.render_template('q.htm', template_values)
```

The log file where the first hit is OK and the reload fails is [here](http://pastebin.com/PceZgf2d).

### Update

The bug is changing. Now it just didn't happen until the third hit of the 2nd page. It doesn't make sense at all not to encounter a pagination error until the third hit of the second page. This is absurd so tell me what is going on and how to investigate the trace? I changed the code to say more about the trace but python doesn't inform me what it is:

It's not only RegionSearch that's failing, it's also search for empty string on pages after page 2. Since it never happens on the first page I suspect this must have something to do with the `cursor`but I've been totally unable to figure out what is wrong with the cursor. The exception doesn't tell me anything, it just says ´this is not working´and nothing about why. I changed handling but it didn't generate any more output about the error: `return

```
index.search(query)
    except search.Error as e:
        logging.exception('Search failed %s', e)`
```

It does occur randomöly without seeming to be a timeout and the exception does not inform about the problem, all it says is "search failed" and the query that fails, a query which works if I put it in the search field. So it doesnt make sense anyhow.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, only appears from page 2 and when I'm sorting.. many others seem to have similar problems

Comment: @luca I actually solved this but I don't remember how. I'll take a look what I did and will get back to you.

Comment: for now I've changed strategy and I'm using multiple indexes with custom ranks so that sorting works fine with pagination.. but I'm still interested in the solution if it exists

Comment: @Programmer400 - Did Something work out finally? I'm facing similar issues now for pagination.

Comment: @minocha Yes I think it was trivial but I don't remember exactly. My appengine app is www.koolbusiness.com and you may have the code if you like. Maybe I just cleared the brower cache or flushed memcache or something similar. I'm going to look in my logs if I can get some more info to help you.

Comment: @Programmer400 - much appreciate it

Comment: @minocha I believe that my mistake was that `default_value` for the date must be historical. So I set it to year 1999. Then it works. Maybe it was also some other problem. The code now works for me and you are welcome to look at it on github if it can help (www.github.com/montao)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only guess that it's RegionSearch that's failing.
You'll need to handle exceptions on your queries.
See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/exceptions

The exception will tell you what the error is.  Hard to guess.

EDIT:

```
try:
    # do query

except search.PutError as e:
    logging.exception('caught PutError %s', e)

except search.InternalError as e:
    logging.exception('caught InternalError %s', e)

except search.DeleteError as e:
    logging.exception('caught DeleteError %s', e)

except search.TransientError as e:
    logging.exception('caught TransientError %s', e)

except search.InvalidRequest as e:
    logging.exception('caught InvalidError %s', e)

except search.Error as e:
    logging.exception('caught unknown error  %s', e)
```

Comment: It's not only RegionSearch that's failing, it's also search for empty string on pages after page 2. Since it never happens on the first page I suspect this must have something to do with the `cursor`but I've been totally unable to figure out what is wrong with the cursor. The exception doesn't tell me anything, it just says ´this is not working´and nothing about why. I changed handling but it didn't generate any more output about the error: `return index.search(query)
    except search.Error as e:
        logging.exception('Search failed %s', e)`

Comment: what's the type of the exception that you're getting?

Comment: I'm trying to investiaget that but I don't know how to do it. Python doesn't say any thing more helpful than just `search fails` I know nothing about what is failing.

Comment: For starters, try catching the various types of search exceptions to see which it is: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/exceptions

Comment: It says it's an invalidrequest error and nothing about why. It's like getting the message "error" with nothing about why. It doesn't help me at all categorizing the error as an InvalidRequest.

Comment: You need to create a simple example that shows the problem.  There is too much code here for any one to wade through and means no one can try and replicate what you are doing.  The errors you are getting are coming from googles infrastructure, and as such you don't have a lot to work with.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thank you for the comment. I'm still investigating this error with almost nothing to go on. It should be possible to examine the stacktrace but I've failed in doing so. I agree it's a good idea to try and recreate the problem in a simple example.

Comment: Is it reproducible or random?  If it's random it might just be something wrong with the underlying google fabric.  You can retry on the InvalidRequest error.  btw, 10k is a pretty huge limit to set, you're at risk of timing out there.

Comment: @dragonx It is sort of random. Sometime it doesn't happen until I reload the 2nd page thrice, on the third hit the error will occur and then on all subsequent hits until I start pagin from the beginning. The live site is www.koolbusiness.com where you may inspect the problem by paging forward thru the large datasets based on geography. It would be so nice if we could get this to work since it is the only bug in the project. I'm tryiing to investigate the stacktrace but I'm not getting very useful information. I can reproduce the error by paging forward.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the **SortExpression**'s **default_value** to **None**, that worked for me.

I was getting the same issue in my Test/QA instance however in my PROD instance worked fine, setting the default_value to None solved the problem in the Test/QA instance for good.